# Add and remove active class on elements on a page based on radio buttons being checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have 3 radio buttons, I want each checked function to apply an active class to a certain element on a page which will control the content being 'active'.

I have managed to get the active class working on one radio, but I'm having trouble removing the class when unchecked and writing the code for the other two radio buttons in an efficient way as my JS knowledge is basic af.

Here's what I have for the one working addClass:

```
$("input#Beach").click(function () {
     if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
         $("#formBeach").addClass("active");
     }
});
```

So again, how do I remove this class when unchecked? and include the other two radio's to do the same thing.

Update: here's the radio html

```
<ul class="form-group mb-0">
    <label>Choose your holiday: </label>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="Tour" name="holiday" checked>
        <label for="Tour">Tour</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="Cruise" name="holiday">
        <label for="Cruise">Cruise</label>
   </li>
   <li>
        <input type="radio" id="Beach" name="holiday">
        <label for="Beach">Beach</label>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Just to clarify, each radio controls a form, only one form can be 'active' at one time, therefore i need the 'unchecked' radio buttons to remove the active classes from their targeted elements.

Comment: toggleClass and change event

Comment: As far as i understood your question, i have posted a answer, please review & let me know, if you have any query. I hope, it may solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an id to your ul element

```
 <ul id="holidays" class="form-group mb-0">
    <label>Choose your holiday: </label>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="Tour" name="holiday" checked>
        <label for="Tour">Tour</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="Cruise" name="holiday">
        <label for="Cruise">Cruise</label>
   </li>
   <li>
        <input type="radio" id="Beach" name="holiday">
        <label for="Beach">Beach</label>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Then:

```
$("#holidays :input").click(function () {
    $("#holidays :input").each(function() {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#form" + $(this).attr("id")).addClass("active");
      } else {
        $("#form" + $(this).attr("id")).removeClass("active");
      }
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know what #form is doing here? I don't have that ID and you can't use the same ID twice on a page really. I want to apply the active class to specific other element classes elsewhere on the page based on each individual checked radio button

Comment: #form is because in your example your form was called #formBeach, please see that im not using any ID twice because im concatenating #form to the ID of the radio button. I assumed you would name your forms #formBeach, #formCruise and #formTour

Comment: In this case,when you click a radio, you will iterate the radio buttons, adding the class to the form related to the radio checked(by ID as explained above) and removing the class from the others

Answer (score 0):

In your particular case, checking the `checked` attribute is even not necessary.

```js
$('.form-group > li').find('input').change(function(){
$('.form-group > li').find('label').addClass('hidden');
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).parent().find('label').toggleClass('hidden');
  }
});
```

```css
#formBeach {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: blue;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  display: block !important;
}

.hidden {
display: none;
}

$('.form-group > li').find('input')is(":checked")) {
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul class="form-group mb-0">
  <label>Choose your holiday: </label>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="Tour" name="holiday" checked>
    <label for="Tour" >Tour</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="Cruise" name="holiday">
    <label for="Cruise" class='hidden'>Cruise</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="Beach" name="holiday">
    <label for="Beach" class='hidden'>Beach</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I would go down that route, but like I said I have 3 radio buttons that control different forms. So i need one form displayed at a time, hence the purpose of the radio buttons; if they're unchecked it will remove the class.

Comment: @LouisAnderson Ah, radio buttons. My mistake. Can you provide more html? With the forms.

Comment: the forms can be named whatever, relative to the radios or of course, but i've updated the question

Comment: @LouisAnderson If the radio button is checked, you want the specified text to appear? Example - Second is checked - 'Cruise' text only appears?

Comment: @LouisAnderson Are you there?

Answer (score 0):

Is this you were trying.@louis

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 
 $("input#gender").click(function () {
     $('.genderspan').removeClass('active');
  var activespan=$(this).attr('data-gender');
  $('.'+activespan).addClass('active');
});

});
```

```css
.genderspan.active{ color:#0C3;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender"  data-gender='Male' value="male" checked> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" data-gender='Female'  value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender"  data-gender='Other' value="other"> Other 
  
  <br>
  <span class="Male genderspan active">Male</span><br>
   <span class="Female genderspan">FeMale</span><br>
    <span class="Other genderspan">Other</span><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add a common `class` into the input radio buttons & create event on that class click. I have added some extra `parameters` in your input radio buttons for matching the `id` of your forms.

Please keep the `id` of form & `data-form` value of radio button same.

Please find your updated code:

```
<ul class="form-group mb-0">
    <label>Choose your holiday: </label>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="Tour" name="holiday" class="check" data-form="form1" checked>
        <label for="Tour">Tour</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" id="Cruise" name="holiday" class="check" data-form="form2" />
        <label for="Cruise">Cruise</label>
   </li>
   <li>
        <input type="radio" id="Beach" name="holiday" class="check" data-form="form3" />
        <label for="Beach">Beach</label>
   </li>
</ul>

<form name="form1" id="form1" class="form active">
1
</form>
<form name="form2" id="form2"  class="form">
2
</form>
<form name="form3" id="form3"  class="form">
3
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".check").click(function () {
    $(".form").removeClass("active");
     if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var form = $(this).data('form');
        //alert(form);
        $('#'+form).addClass("active");
     }
});
</script>
```

Please remove the extra code as per your requirement.
Just copy and replace with your code.

Hope, it may be useful to you.